# Java/reflection - where's error?

Tags: java, reflection

I found some posts about java/reflection on this site. But still can't understand something. Could anyone tell where's error in my code? (need to print "HELLO!")

Output:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Caller.foo()
```

Here's my `Main.java`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Caller cal = new Caller();
        Method met;
        try {
            met = cal.getClass().getMethod("foo", new Class[]{});
            met.invoke(cal);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}

class Caller {
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("HELLO!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) only finds `public` methods. Either change the access modifier of the `Caller#foo()` method to `public`, or use [`getDeclaredMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) instead.

Comment: Yes, the scope for `foo()` is package-private (no explicit modifier)

Comment: Yeah! getDeclaredMethod() - cause I need to keep both classes in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName("Caller"); 
            Object obj = c.newInstance();
            Method m = c.getMethod("foo");
            m.invoke(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }           
    }
}

public class Caller {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("HELLO!");
    }
}
```